# Why I can't play video in react using the video tag?

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

To play a video in react I have to write the video tag as:

```
<video className='myVideo' src={require('./../video/video.mp4')} controls> </video>
```

see how I Have to mention the source of the video. Is there any other way to achieve the same result?

I want to update the source when a state changes, but, I am unable to do so. Because when I replace the string in the require function with a state variable, it gives the following error:

**Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression**

I have created the react app using the following command:
npx create-react-app

Comment: can you share how you are updating the source state ?

Answer (score 0):

In react you use source tag too.
example code:

```
<video  loop autoPlay>
    <source src= { covervid } type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    <source src={ covervidtwo } type="video/ogg" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
```